# How To Install D-Link DWM-156 3G Modem Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: usb, usb-modem, modem, 3g

I bought a new D-Link 3G modem and it said it supports Linux. But after I installed it, I still can't make the device work on Ubuntu 13.10.

I used the .deb file from the D-link modem 3g_modem_connect_DWM156_amd64.deb (from the modem itself) but I was unable to configure it. I searched the Internet, they use dlinkusbmodem.deb file, which is a file from 1 year ago. Even after I dpkg it, I still don't know how to proceed.

I've used every method in the askubuntu, it don't work with this file version.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.deb` file must work. It is rare in your case that it does not works.

In that sense, just use NetworkManager (`nm`) to connect your modem over mobile broad band which is the default.

Eject the driver cd of your modem as soon as you plug in the modem from the terminal or DISKS. thats all your modem will be seen in the nm after 10s as new connection.
Configure it & use it.

Cou can also make this automatic using usb mode switch. You just need to add your device `id` to it.